# How to read bean value within Renderer

Tags: jsf-1.2, renderer

I am writing a custom jsf `Renderer` for checkboxes and radio buttons to render without `TABLE` element. My question is if I have a select box like below

```
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="vehicle" value="#{pageBean.vehicle}>
       <f:selectItems value="#{pageBean.vehiclesList} />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

in the `encodeBegin` method how can I read the `vehiclesList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was straight forward.

```
Iterator<UIComponent> iterator = component.getFacetsAndChildren();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    UIComponent childComponent = iterator.next();
    List vehicles = childComponent.getValueExpression("value").getValue(context.getELContext);
    // Do whatever with vehicles.
}
```

Here I assumed that there is only one child to the main component which is SelectItems.